# Query based on Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
    int arr[2][3][2]={{{2,4},{7,8},{3,4},}, {{2,2},{2,3},{3,4}, }};
    cout<<**(*arr+1)+2+7;
}
```

According to me answer will be 11, But compiler is showing 16.
Can anyone please explain the solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think the answer should be 11?

Comment: The expression `*arr+1` doesn't do what you expect it to do, I think. Try to first get it working right with array indexing syntax, then use gradually turn each array index to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @cricket_007 actually i m using element de-referencing. That is the reason for my wrong answer. Now. I got the explanation thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*arr` is equivalent to `arr[0]`.

`*(arr[0]+1)` is equivalent to `arr[0][1]`.

`*arr[0][1]` is equivalent to `arr[0][1][0]`.

So, your code is equivalent to this:

```
#include<iostream.h>

void main()
{
    int arr[2][3][2]={
      {{2,4},{7,8},{3,4},},
      {{2,2},{2,3},{3,4},}
    };
    cout << arr[0][1][0]+2+7;
}
```

`arr[0][1][0]` is 7, so you get 7+2+7, which is 16.

Answer (score 2):

```
**(*arr + 1) + 2 + 7
```

Is the same as

```
**(arr[0] + 1) + 2 + 7
```

Same as

```
arr[0][1][0] + 2 + 7
```

`arr[0][1][0]` Is 7 by definition.

So the compiler is correct and answer is 16.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct. Try doing this in your code to see it in action for yourself:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int arr[2][3][2]=
      {
        {
          {2,4},{7,8},{3,4},
        },
        {
          {2,2},{2,3},{3,4},
        }
      };
    std::cout << *arr << std::endl;            // 0x7fff5a3a6710
    std::cout << *arr+1 << std::endl;          // 0x7fff5a3a6718
    std::cout << *(*arr+1) << std::endl;       // 0x7fff5a3a6718
    std::cout << **(*arr+1) << std::endl;      // 7
    std::cout << **(*arr+1)+2+7 << std::endl;  // 16

    return 0;
}
```